# How to add a force 90 degrees / sideways from a forward vector3 direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 cubes, one big, one small, the larger cube will be stationary, while the smaller cube will be given a force towards
the larger cube with :

```
smallerCube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce((largeCube.transform.position - smallerCube.transform.position).normalized * force);
```

now I want to find out how to add a force with a 90 degree offset on the Y axis from the above given direction

```
largeCube.transform.position - smallerCube.transform.position
```

so it will seem to orbit the largerCube with a force towards it as well as a sideways force with a 90 degree offset from the 'towards' direction.

how would I go about doing something like that, using Rigidbody physics.

Comment: A orbiting object only has a force towards the center, staring with a fixed speed across in a perpendicular direction

Comment: You want centrifugal force (spinning).  See : https://forum.unity.com/threads/centrifugal-force-physics-gravity.169226/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You rotate a vector by simply multiply it with the according rotation using the [`*` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-operator_multiply.html).

For an offset of 90° in the global Y axis you can use [`Quaternion.Euler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Euler.html) like e.g.

```
var rotatedDirection = Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0) * (largeCube.transform.position - smallerCube.transform.position).normalized;
```